# Downloading and Storing Google Map tiles in SQL server 2014/2017

Tags: google-maps, sql-server-2014

i am working on an GIS application that navigates real time traffic using offline Google Maps, i am Using Leaflet for the interaction with Maps. I want to Download and Store Google map tiles, very few (just for testing purposes). Can anyone please guide from where should i download these tiles and how to store them in SQL server. it would mean a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is explicitly prohibited by Terms of Services of Google Maps APIs. You cannot download and save Google Maps tiles. Have a look at paragraph 10.1 (a) of ToS, it reads:

> **No access to APIs or Content except through the Service.** You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, **you must not access map tiles or imagery** through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#10-license-restrictions